# Matrix in QTableWidget or sql

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt

I need to create a graph adjacency matrix, I first wanted to just create a qtablewidget, but it doesn't save values after closing. Can this be done? Or it's better to create an sql database, but I can't come up with an output that produces a matrix like a multiplication table. My idea is to create records so that there are 3 columns: node1, node2 and edge. Something like this:

`"CREATE TABLE userlist ( "
           "node1 VARCHAR(20),"
           "node2 VARCHAR(20), "
           "edge VARCHAR(20));"`

The formation of the standard output is not suitable.

```
model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
model ->setTable("graphlist");
model ->select();
ui_Main->tableView->setModel(model);
```

[matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W606p.png)

Comment: Do you want a graph or a multiplication table? Or some kind of a combination of both? Please explain what do you wish to do with the graph stored like that in an SQL database.

Comment: I need the adjacency matrix of the graph, I can't output it so that it looks like an Archimedean multiplication table

Comment: So all you want is the adjacency matrix of the graph printed in the table.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your intention completely. But I assume you have stored a graph in your database using a table with the columns `node1, node2, edge`.
Now you want a table showing the adjacency matrix.

I suggest using a `QAbstractTableModel` for your output table, by giving data from a 2D array. And then synchronize the 2D array with the database using `QSqlTableModel`.

Something on the lines of:

Inherit the abstract class `QAbstractTableModel` to a class `MyModel` and add a static 2D array or a vector to it. Override the `data` function with the following

```
QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole){
    return QVariant(MyModel::array[index.row()][index.column()]);
}
```

Also you will have to populate the 2D array

```
model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
model ->setTable("graphlist"); 
model ->select();
for (int i=0;I<model->rowCount();++i){

MyModel::array[model.record(i).value("node1").toInt()][model.record(i).value("node2").toInt()]=model.record(i).value("edge").toInt();
```

I am sorry my code might give some confusion about `.` or `->` but I am sure you can handle them accordingly in your code.

Also I don't know why you used `varchar` in your table. It is best if you use int. But if that is necessary, then you can have another string array for storing those `varchar` items and mapping them.